# getSiblings() and sort_by error

Tags: sorting, liferay, freemarker

I am working in Liferay with structure (XML) and template (FTL).

My problem is that I do not get how I can use a `sort_by()` together with `getSiblings()`.

This code does not work, as an example:

```
<ul id="emedia-categories">
  <#list category?sort_by('linktext').getSiblings() as cat>
    <li>
      <a href="${cat.path.getData()}" title="${cat.title.getData()}">
        <h3>
          ${cat.linktext.getData()}
        </h3>
        <img src="${cat.image.getData()}" alt="image-alt">
      </a>
    </li>
  </#list>
</ul>
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Expected sequence. category evaluated instead to com.liferay.portal.freemarker.LiferayTemplateModel on line 2, column 16 in 14868#14904#131571.
```

What I want to achieve is to loop over all data and while doing it, I want it to be sorted on the string which is inside each `cat.linktext`. So the result comes out like: A, B, C, D, E...

Instead of: D, B, E, A, C...

This is my only working variant, but it does not have any sort on `linktext`, it just loop data in the order it is entered (probably by id):

```
<ul id="emedia-categories">
  <#list category.getSiblings() as cat>
    <li>
      <a href="${cat.path.getData()}" title="${cat.title.getData()}">
        <h3>
          ${cat.linktext.getData()}
        </h3>
        <img src="${cat.image.getData()}" alt="image-alt">
      </a>
    </li>
  </#list>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: You are *trying* to sort the category, which is not a sequence (= a list or array).

You *want* to sort the siblings, which is a sequence (= a list), by the attribute `linktext.data`:

```
<#list category.siblings?sort_by(['linktext', 'data']) as cat>
 ...
<#/list>
```

Comment: Yes, I guess the error message was quite clear. But I could not figure out the solution. Thanks.